# How can I print all the values of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, web-applications

I have an array and print_r won't display the raw text, how can I print all the values in an array (e.g. pie)

Comment: `print_r` & `var_dump` both do this, can you post some code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So many ways to do it...

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}

echo join(', ', $array);

array_walk($array, create_function('$a', 'echo $a;'));
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you just need some `<pre>` tags:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
$len=count($pie);
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
   echo $pie[$i];
?>
```