# need to change mysqli_query output format by php file

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am using php file to retrieve data from MYSQL server, and the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Abbasya [1] => Alex Auto [2] => Alex Post [3] => Banisweif [4] => Nasr City [5] => Ramsis TE [6] => Smart Village ).
```

I need to change the output to be like below as I need to convert the String into string [] in my android app.

needed output (to just print the values):

```
"Abbasya", "Alex Auto", "Alex Post", "BaniSweif", "Nasr City", "Ramsis TE", "Smart Village"
```

what is the needed changes on the below php code to generate the required output

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT core_site FROM core_sites");
$coresites = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$coresites[] = $row['core_site'];
}
print_r($coresites);
?>
```

Many Thanks for your support :)

Comment: You can try implod for convert array to string or you can use json_encode () for android web service

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528097/how-can-i-print-all-the-values-of-an-array

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
require "init.php";
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT core_site FROM core_sites");
$coresites = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$coresites[] = $row['core_site'];
}
echo json_encode($coresites);

// or 

echo implode($coresites);
```

Comment: Many thanks Amit, It works :)  .. I used json_encode .. Appreciated :)